# Make thumbnails scroll horizontally without using nowrap

Tags: html, css, nowrap

I'm trying to make the below design using CSS:

[image]

The idea is to make it scroll horizontally in a full-width container.

I added **white-space: nowrap** to the wrapper, but because the text is too long it goes out it's container. Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Please check the the live jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shadeed9/mm79vdwt/3/)

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="col-lg-4 box-item">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typeset industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever hen an with new version look.</h2>
            <h3>Ahmad Shadeed <span>- Wamda</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 box-item">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typeset industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever hen an with new version look.</h2>
            <h3>Ahmad Shadeed <span>- Wamda</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.box .box-item {
  background: #eeeeee;
  margin: 0 10px;
  transition: background 0.4s ease;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: none;
}
```

PS: I read about using display:table and table-cell, any ideas if it's possible to do that with them?

Thanks,

Comment: How about disabling for children? i.e. `.content{white-space:normal}` [See in your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mm79vdwt/4/)

Comment: I would add `padding: 0px 10px;` to the `.content` rule as well

Comment: @JNF it works! thank you :) let's see other members suggestions.

Comment: You should look into using overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css is inherited by the inner elements. You can specify fitting css for the children by adding a rule such as

```
.content {
    white-space: normal;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

[In your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mm79vdwt/4/)

Comment: Please check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shadeed9/mm79vdwt/5/
I removed some text from the first one and it's height decreased. Is there a way to make the height fixed?

Comment: Added `h2` rule in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mm79vdwt/6/). YOu should verify the set height there really meets your needs. You might want to adjust.